# Yii2 - Data deleted

Tags: php, yii2

i'm running a Yii2 application. Today I encountered a problem, where a whole table with at least 250 entries was totally empty. The table consisted of file information entries (original filename, new filename). So every entry was - logically - linked to an file in the file system. I checked the files of the file system and saw, that the files also where deleted. So i concluded that the data was deleted within the yii2 application. I have an action which will be called (POST) to delete one entry.

I did a kind of generic function for it:

```
public function actionDelete($id, $className)
{
    $this->findModel($id, $className)->delete();       
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

In the view i have a list of file attachments with action columns. Every action column has this method call:

```
echo TagHelper::deleteButton($attachment, Yii::t('app', 'Deleting a File'));
```

Where `$attachment` is the model.

and `deleteButton` looks like this:

```
public static function deleteButton($model, $text, $view = null, $controller = 'delete/delete-check') {
    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', FALSE, ['value' => Url::to([$controller, 'id' => $model->id, 'className' => get_class($model), 'view' => $view]),
                'role' => 'button', 'title' => $text,
                'class' => 'showModalButton btn-link'
    ]);
}
```

this will open up a modal window with the view `delete/delete-check` opens up an modal window and looks like this:

```
<div class="delete-check">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'delete-check-form', 
        'method' => 'post', 
        'action'=>['delete', 'id' => $model->id, 'className' => get_class($model)]
    ]); ?>  

    <?php if ($model->deleteable()): ?>
        <p><?= Yii::t('app', 'You are going to delete the following entry:') ?></p>
        <div class="well well-sm"><?= $model ?></div>
        <p><?= Yii::t('app', "In the system there aren't any references to this entry found. Deleting this entry won't lead to any problems." ) ?></p>
        <p><?= Yii::t('app', "Deleting this entry is <mark>definitive</mark> and can't be undone." ) ?></p>

        <div class="form-group text-right">
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Delete'), ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>
        <p><?= Yii::t('app', "You can't delete the entry:") ?> </p>
        <div class="well well-sm"><?= $model ?></div>
        <p><?= Yii::t('app', "There are the following references found in the system:" ) ?></p>

            <?php echo $this->render('/' . $view . '/_reference.php', ['model' => $model]); ?>

        <div class="form-group text-right">           
          <?= Html::button(Yii::t('app', 'Ok'), ['data-dismiss' => 'modal', 'class' => 'btn btn-info']); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Can this be the problem?

The application itself manages more than 40 users. They enter different data for their account. So deleting over 250 entries from that table can't be possible, since the user doesn't even see those entries. He only sees his own entries.

So my question is, is there a possibility that somehow the delete action is called in a irregular matter?

I'm really stuck here, since i have no idea where to start investigating. Some clues?

cheerz,
Luc

**Edit:**

and the `findModel` function:

```
protected function findModel($id, $className)
{
    if (($model = $className::findModel($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

the actual call of the `$className::findModel()` method for the `$attachment` model:

```
public static function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = EnsembleProposalHealthAttachment::findOne($id)) !== null) {
       if (Yii::$app->user->can("admin") || Yii::$app->user->id == $model->ensembleProposal->ensemble->theater->user_id) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));
        }
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**
I looked into the yii2 log files and could find some interesting exceptions (from a different model, with the same delete logic), which may belongs to that problem.

```
2017-10-09[][][][error][yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: The requested page does not exist. in models/EnsembleProposalProductionAttachment.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 controllers/DeleteController.php(73): app\models\EnsembleProposalProductionAttachment::findModel('168')
#1 controllers/DeleteController.php(66): app\controllers\DeleteController->findModel('168', 'app\\models\\Ense...')
#2 [internal function]: app\controllers\DeleteController->actionDelete('168', 'app\\models\\Ense...')
```

I'm still can't imagine how this error is even thrown, since calling the findModel with a wrong id isn't possible from the frontend.

May this probably has something todo with the line:

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

that somehow the referrer holds an incorrect value?

Comment: add `findModel()` function

Comment: The `findModel()` of the `$className` involved would be handy as well. There is a big chance you have got there a query condition that is not limiting the rows to be deleted hence the problem.

Comment: @Bizley thanks for the reply, unfortunately i don't get what you are saying. Can you make an example? I updated the question to show the $className::findModel method of the actual $attachment model

Comment: This looks fine so my suspicion is not right. Something else is happening.

Comment: @Bizley ok, just updated my question again.

Answer (score 0):

always work with backup! In this case you are lose